# Derived class doesn't conform to protocol

Tags: swift

```
    import Foundation
    import Swift


    struct HasType<Type: AnyObject> {
        static func inObject<T>(object: T) -> Bool {
            return object is Type
        }
    }


    @objc protocol MyBaseProtocol : class {}
    @objc protocol MyDerivedProtocol : MyBaseProtocol {}
    @objc class MyBaseClass : MyDerivedProtocol {}
    @objc class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass {}

    let mbc = MyBaseClass()
    let mdc = MyDerivedClass()

    HasType<MyBaseProtocol>.inObject(mbc) // True
    HasType<MyDerivedProtocol>.inObject(mbc) // True
    HasType<MyBaseProtocol>.inObject(mdc) // False
    HasType<MyDerivedProtocol>.inObject(mdc) // False
    HasType<MyBaseClass>.inObject(mdc) // True
    HasType<MyDerivedClass>.inObject(mdc) // True
```

Why does this methods returns 2 False. I expect All True. What have I missed? All this code could be pasted in playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug. The problem can be simplified as:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {}
class MyBaseClass : MyProtocol {}
class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass {}

let mbc:AnyObject = MyBaseClass()
let mdc:AnyObject = MyDerivedClass()

mbc is MyProtocol // -> true
mdc is MyProtocol // -> false
```

The workaround is to make `MyBaseClass` inherits from `NSObject`

```
class MyBaseClass : NSObject, MyProtocol { }
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug. The other workaround I found is to Make MyDerivedClass comply to MyDeriveProtocol. `class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass, MyDerivedProtocol {}`

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct HasType<Type: AnyObject> {
static func inObject<T>(object: T) -> Bool {
    return object is Type
 }
}
@objc protocol MyBaseProtocol {
func someValue() -> Double
}
@objc protocol MyDerivedProtocol : MyBaseProtocol{}
@objc class MyBaseClass : MyDerivedProtocol {
func someValue() -> Double { return 9.9 }
}
@objc class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass, MyDerivedProtocol {}

let mbc = MyBaseClass()
let mdc = MyDerivedClass()
mdc.someValue()

HasType<MyBaseProtocol>.inObject(mbc) // True
HasType<MyDerivedProtocol>.inObject(mbc) // True
HasType<MyBaseProtocol>.inObject(mdc) // true
HasType<MyDerivedProtocol>.inObject(mdc) // true
HasType<MyBaseClass>.inObject(mdc) // True
HasType<MyDerivedClass>.inObject(mdc) // True
```

Note that, you won't have to reimplement the `MyDerivedProtocol` methods and requirement since that has been already taken care of by `MyBaseClass`. This seems like a roundabout way of doing things.